# Replace doc by unidoc in publish-local

Tags: sbt, documentation-generation, multi-project

I have a sbt project in a multi-prject structure. So I want to use unidoc for documentation generation. But publish-local uses always doc. How can you replace doc by unidoc. I am using sbt 0.12.4.

I found this [Disable sbt subproject doc generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937344/disable-sbt-subproject-doc-generation),

but this seems to be a solution for sbt 0.13